# SyntaxError: invalid token in datetime.datetime(2012,05,22,09,03,41)?

Tags: python, datetime

I do something like this:

```
>>>import datetime
>>>datetime.datetime(2012,05,22,05,03,41)
datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 22, 5, 3, 41)

>>> datetime.datetime(2012,05,22,07,03,41)
datetime.datetime(2012,05,22,07,03,41)

>>> datetime.datetime(2012,05,22,9,03,41)
datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 22, 9, 3, 41)

>>> datetime.datetime(2012,05,22,09,03,41)
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Why I get SyntaxError? How to fix it?

Comment: 09 isn't valid octal digit...

Comment: @Xaerxess: 09 isn't valid octal **number** - apologies, I'm feeling picky today :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Yeah, what I meant was **9** is a valid decimal **digit** :)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In Python 2, a number starting with `0` is interpreted as an *octal* number, often leading to confusion for those not familiar with C integer literal notations. In Python 3, you cannot start a number with `0` at all.

Remove the leading 0s:

```
datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 22, 9, 3, 41)
```

The error is caused by `09` not being a valid octal number:

```
>>> 010
8
>>> 09
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    09
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```